# Preg split but make delimiter a part

Tags: php

If i have the following string:

```
string-with-word-split-should-be-split-here
```

and I want to split the string on the last occurrence of the word split but that word should be part of the returned results - how do i do this?  `preg_split` nor explode allow this.

The result i would be looking for would be:

```
array(
   'string-with-word-split-should-be', 'split-here'
);
```

i could use explode, grab what i need and make two arrays imploding etc.  But that seems like i am overlooking a better solution.  Am i?

Comment: with your string as example, the return shouldn't be more like `array( 'string-with-word-split', -should-be-split', '-here')` ?

Comment: If you're using preg_split(), why not simply use the PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE flag? Or am I missing something esoteric in the question? Or if it's including the hyphen if you use PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE then you can remove that using a trim() after the split

Answer (score 0):

If `preg_split` works fine except the word split is missing, you can still add it after in a loop. Otherwise, use `preg_match_all`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [`strrpos`](http://www.php.net/strrpos) and [`substr`](http://www.php.net/substr)?

```
<?php
    $string = 'string-with-word-split-should-be-split-here';

    $splitPosition = strrpos($string, 'split-');
    if ($splitPosition !== false) {
        $split = array(
            trim(substr($string, 0, $splitPosition), '-'), 
            trim(substr($string, $splitPosition), '-')
        );
    } else {
        $split = array($string);
    }

    print_r($split);
?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => string-with-word-split-should-be
    [1] => split-here
)
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/uTfrXL8I)